# In JavaScript using both linq.js and knockout.js, how can I generate an observableArray that contains a computed property?

Tags: javascript, linq, functional-programming, knockout.js, linq.js

Sorry if my title makes no sense but this is what I've gotten down to so far:

```
function createPostsArray(last) {
                var postArr = 
                    generate(
                        function () { 
                            return { 
                                postGroup: [], 
                                visible: computed(
                                            function (){ //return true if 
                                                         //postGroup is empty
                            } 
                        }, last)
                    .toArray();

                posts(postArr);

            }
```

basically, is postGroup[] is empty, I want to display a "loading" screen using CSS. When postGroup gets some elements, automatically visible should become false.

Later I will extend this computed function to also consider another observable, but this is tricky for me since visible is dependent on a specific postGroup, the one with which it is associated.

How can I do this? Does anyone know?

PS: Generate is a linq.js generate function and Computed is a ko.computed function

PS: What is a good reference to read on these concepts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The knockout portion would look like this.  postGroup would need to be an observableArray because you want to observe the array itself.  Because visible is a ko.computed it will run its function whenever the number of elements in postGroup change.

The extend({ throttle: 100 }) isn't necessary, but if postGroup is populated via repetitive postGroup.push() calls it will aid performance.  It causes a computed observable to delay re-evaluation until its dependencies have stopped changing for a specified period of time. http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/throttle-extender.html

```
return { 
    postGroup: ko.observableArray(), 
    visible: ko.computed(function() {
        return postGroup().length > 0;
    }).extend({ throttle: 100 })
}
```